# Join tables and update column on multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `customers` and `orders`, where important columns are:

```
/* Customers: */
id        | login     | membershipid
100       | email1    | 0
101       | email2    | 0

/* Orders: */
userid    | total
100       | 150
101       | 120
101       | 450
```

I want to update `membershipid` depending of total purchases for each customer. Lets say it will be zero if the sum is less than 500, one if sum is 500-1000, two if sum is over 1000.

I get the sum this way:

```
SELECT customers.login, sum( orders.total ) AS total_purchased 
FROM xcart_customers AS customers
LEFT JOIN xcart_orders AS orders ON customers.id = orders.userid
GROUP BY customers.login
```

but I am not sure how to update back customers table. Something like:

```
UPDATE xcart_customers set (membershipid) = (
    SELECT sum( orders.total ) AS total_purchased 
    FROM xcart_customers AS customers
    LEFT JOIN xcart_orders AS orders ON customers.id = orders.userid
    GROUP BY customers.login
)
```

but where and how to use conditions (and will `GROUP BY` work?):

```
CASE 
    WHEN 
    ..
    ELSE 
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is with a join operation. Take your query, and turn it into an inline view, and join that back to the `customers` table.

We might want to handle the case when `total_purchased` is NULL as being less than 500 (when a customer doesn't have any related rows in `xcart_orders`.)

As a SELECT it would look like this:

```
SELECT t.login
     , t.membershipid
     , CASE 
         WHEN IFNULL(s.total_purchased,0) < 500 THEN 0
         WHEN s.total_purchased <= 1000 THEN 1
         WHEN s.total_purchased > 1000 THEN 2
         ELSE NULL
       END AS new_membershipid
  FROM customers t
  JOIN ( SELECT c.login
              , SUM(o.total) AS total_purchased 
           FROM xcart_customers c
           LEFT 
           JOIN xcart_orders o 
             ON o.userid = c.id 
          GROUP BY c.login
       ) s
    ON s.login = t.login
```

---

To convert that into an UPDATE, replace the `SELECT ... FROM` with `UPDATE`

and add a `SET` clause at the end of the statement (before the WHERE clause if there was a WHERE clause).

For example:

```
UPDATE customers t
  JOIN ( SELECT c.login
              , SUM(o.total) AS total_purchased 
           FROM xcart_customers c
           LEFT 
           JOIN xcart_orders o 
             ON o.userid = c.id 
          GROUP BY c.login
       ) s
    ON s.login = t.login
   SET t.membershipid =
       CASE 
         WHEN IFNULL(s.total_purchased,0) < 500 THEN 0
         WHEN s.total_purchased <= 1000 THEN 1
         WHEN s.total_purchased > 1000 THEN 2
         ELSE NULL
       END
```

---

NOTE: This assumes that `login` is UNIQUE` in the customers table.

**FOLLOWUP**

Given that membershipid cannot be assigned a NULL value, we can tweak the CASE expression. Do the check for > 1000 first, then a check for >= 500, else 0.

For example:

```
       CASE 
         WHEN s.total_purchased > 1000 THEN 2
         WHEN s.total_purchased >= 500 THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END
```

Comment: The `ELSE NULL` is not required; that's the default when an `ELSE` is omitted. The CASE expression can be modified.. do the check for `> 1000` first, followed by a check for >= 500, followed by an `ELSE 0`.

Comment: Just saying `ELSE` would never be executed, right? It should go in above line where you have `s.total_purchased > 1000`.

Comment: @skobaljic: right. the way I wrote that CASE expression, we'd never enter the ELSE NULL. I was just writing that expression in the same order that specification was given. I prefer the re-write in the followup.  If total_purchased is over 1000, then 2. If it's over (or equal to) 500, then 1. else 0. You can tweak the CASE expression to match the specification, just want to make sure it "works" before you run an UPDATE.

Comment: Tested and everything works fine. Thank you for your effort, also many thanks to [juergen-d](http://stackoverflow.com/users/575376/juergen-d) and his fast answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE xcart_customers 
join
(
    SELECT customers.login, sum( orders.total ) AS total_purchased 
    FROM xcart_customers AS customers
    LEFT JOIN xcart_orders AS orders ON customers.id = orders.userid
    GROUP BY customers.login
) tmp on tmp.login = xcart_customers.login
set xcart_customers.membershipid = case when total_purchased is null or total_purchased < 500 then 0
                                        when total_purchased between 500 and 1000 then 1
                                        else 2
                                   end
```

Comment: should we handle the condition when `total_purchased` is null differently than assigning 2 to membershipid ?

Comment: null or less than 500 should be membership zero (the way you specified spencer).

Comment: @skobaljic: when writing update queries like this, I recommend you write it as a SELECT first... return the columns you are matching on, and the new value you plan to assign, and make sure that's working correctly, before you convert it into an UPDATE. (That's the way I roll.) The CASE expression can be modified to handle the NULL value, for example: **`when total_purchased is null then 0`**.